# Is Java generics required in this Dictionary code?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

In the below code, `interface Dictionary` has some methods using `Object` type as parameter.

```
/* Dictionary.java */

package cs61b.homework6.dict;

public interface Dictionary {

    public int size();

    public boolean isEmpty();

    class Entry { 

        protected Object key;
        protected Object value;

        public Object key() {
            return key;
        }

        public Object value() {
            return value;
        }

    }


    public Entry insert(Object key, Object value);
    public Entry find(Object key);

    public Entry remove(Object key);

    public void makeEmpty();

}
```

below is the implementation `class HashTableChained` of `interface Dictionary`,

```
/* HashTableChained.java */

package cs61b.homework6.dict;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import JavaCollections.list.DblyLinkList;

public class HashTableChained implements Dictionary {

    private long tableSize;
    private ArrayList<DblyLinkList<Entry>> defTable;

    public HashTableChained(long sizeEstimate) {... }

    public HashTableChained() { ... }
    private static boolean isPrime(long n) { ...}
    private static long nextPrime(long previous) { ..   }

    int compFunction(int code) { ... }

    public int size() { ... }

    public boolean isEmpty() { ...  }

    public Entry insert(Object key, Object value) { ... }

    public Entry find(Object key) { ... }

    public Entry remove(Object key) { ...   }

    public void makeEmpty() { ...}

}
```

I would like to understand, Is there an advantage of introducing `interface Dictionary<K, V>` syntax with `K key` and `V value`?

Note: Java beginner. Complete code is available  [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/cs61b/homework6/dict/HashTableChained.java). Teacher encourages to write own packages instead of using `java.util` collection package.

Comment: Why are you not implementing java.util.Map<K,V> interface?

Comment: Since it does seem like you have no setter for the `Key` and `Value` in your `Entry` the type safety from generics wont be that helpfull at compiletime.

Comment: The advantage should be pretty obvious - it's the same advantage you get by using `ArrayList<DblyLinkList<Entry>>` instead of just `ArrayList`.

Comment: @immibis I used `ArrayList` because `ArrayList` is a generic class. I do not know the advantages that it has by allowing users to use geenric syntax.

Comment: Well what's the advantage of the people who wrote ArrayList using generic syntax? The advantage is that then the people *using* ArrayList get to write `ArrayList<DblyLinkList<Entry>>` instead of just `ArrayList`. Likewise if *you* use it here, the advantage is people (including you) can write `Dictionary<String, List<Integer>>` or whatever instead of just `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an advantage. It will keep you safe(r) during compilation by verifying you're not doing anything completely wrong (like putting a key or a value of the wrong type).

It will also remove (most of) the need to cast in your code when using the map.

if you use `Entry` with `Object`s as keys and values for doing a word count:

```
Dictionary dict = new Dictionary();

dict.insert("word", new Integer(42));

Object count = dict.find("word"); // gives an Object, not an Integer

// need to cast - annoying, not safe
Integer countAsInteger = (Integer)count;
```

If you introduce generics:

```
Dictionary dict = new Dictionary<String, Integer>();

dict.insert("word", new Integer(42));

Integer count = dict.find("word"); // gives an Integer
```

The generic typing also protects you from creating a heterogeneous map. In you implementation this is allowed:

```
dict.insert("word", "42");
```

But it was probably an error. You intended the count to be an `Integer`.

In the generic implementation you will be able to implement:

```
public void insert(K key, V value);
```

Which will not allow (at compilation time) anything other than `K` and `V` in the map.

Comment: @lschuetze guess I'm not completely following what is library code and what is his code.

Comment: For your point: *like putting a key or a value of the wrong type*, No body can stop me in saying `dict.insert(12345, new Integer(42));`. So, generic syntax looks obviously required. Sorry, am a beginner. i think `key.hashCode()` will run `Integer.hashCode` in this case, correct?

Comment: In case of `Dictionary<String, ...>` this statement: `dict.insert(12345, new Integer(42));` will not compile. If you're using the key's `hashCode` than it will run, yes. But it will run anyway (without generics as well). This is in case of a dictionary that uses hashes.